# Javascript reading html input values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a Javascript script that asks the user to enter details about a book, and then it generates an MLA style citation for it. The following is my HTML code.

```
<input type="text" value="Author last name" id="lname"/><br />

<input type="text" value="Title of book" id="booktitle"/><br />


<input type="text" value="City of Publication" id="pubcity"/><br />

<input type="text" value="Publisher" id="pub"/><br />

<input type="text" value="Year of Publication" id="pubyear"/><br />
<input type="text" value="Number of footnote" id="footnote"/>
<br />('Number of footnote' only applicable if you plan to generate a footnote citation.)<br />

<button type="button" onclick="generateBookFootnote()">Generate Footnote</button>
<button type="button" onclick="generateBookEndnote()">Generate Endnote</button> 
</form>
<p id="cite"></p>
```

And my Javascript is as follows.

```
function generateBookFootnote()
{
    //I was just trying to do this, which I got from another StackOverflow question. Result below.
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname');
    var booktitle = document.getElementById('bookititle');
    var pubcity = document.getElementById('pubcity');
    var pubyear = document.getElementById('pubyear');
    var pub = document.getElementById('pub');
    var footnote = document.getElementById('footnote');

    document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML=document.getElementById( fname ); 

};
```

So I've tried many approaches from the Internet, trying to just get it to print out the contents of the text box `fname`. `var fname = document.getElementById('fname');` prints out `[object HTMLInputElement]` not the actual value. The `document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML=document.getElementById( fname );` doesn't print anything when I run the function. Those are the only two solutions I have found on the Internet so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `document.getElementById` returns an object of type HTMLElement, which is the element that has the specified ID. To access its value, use this instead:

```
var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
```

I suggest you to take a look at [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLElement) and [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) MDN documentations

This issue also applies to either [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) and [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) methods, although they all return an array with the matching elements.

Thus, your function should be:

```
function generateBookFootnote()
{
    var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var booktitle = document.getElementById('bookititle').value;
    var pubcity = document.getElementById('pubcity').value;
    var pubyear = document.getElementById('pubyear').value;
    var pub = document.getElementById('pub').value;
    var footnote = document.getElementById('footnote').value;

    document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML = document.getElementById( fname ).value; 

};
```

Comment: So why can't you do `document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML = fname`? When I do that, it returns a blank statement. To clarify, I did put `var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;`.

Comment: Because `document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML = fname` will display `[object HTMLInputElement]`, and not it's value. Actually I didn't understand what you wanted to do in this line, since I couldn't find the element with the `fname` ID (maybe you wanted to do document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML = fname;)

Answer (score 1):

after you select an input element by id with something like:

```
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
```

you can see its current value through the `value` property. for example:

```
console.log(fname.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your code properly. You've used the object instead of id.

```
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');

document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML=document.getElementById( fname );
```

Use this instead

```
document.getElementById("cite").innerHTML=document.getElementById('fname');
```