# Small issue with String.Replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Not being too versed with JS yet, I've run into a weird issue where it seems like `.replace()` *should* be working but isn't.

I'm just trying to take a string (from an element ID) that has text + digits, replace the digits with a RegEx pattern, then replace the original text in that ID with the original text + new digits.

**My HTML sample:**

```
<html>
  <body>

    <p>Click the button to replace "Movies: 12344" with "Movies: 54321" in the paragraph below:</p>

    <p id="demo">Movies: 1234!</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

**My JS:**

```
function myFunction() {

  // Get all the text in #id=demo
  var str = document.getElementById("demo"); 

  // RegEx pattern to find ": <some digits>"
  var pat = /\:\s?\d*/;

  // Replace the digits
  var res = str.replace(pat, ': 54321');

  // Doesn't work (as a test) ...
  //res = " hi"

  // Replace the text in id=demo with original text + new digits.
  str.innerHTML = res;

  // Doesn't work (as a test) ...
  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

At the moment, after clicking the button in the page, nothing happens.

This might help out a bit too:
https://codepen.io/stardogg/pen/aboREmL

Comment: here `var res = str.replace(pat, ': 54321');`  `str` is a HTML element, not a string, i think you forgot to get the content with `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` when setting the `str` value

Comment: Oops, [wrong duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228437/javascript-reading-html-input-values). But very, very similar, just `innerHTML` or `textContent` instead of `value`.

Comment: Aha! `var res = str.innerHTML.replace(pat, ': 54321');` did it, thanks @CalvinNunes and @T.J. Crowder.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you're setting the `innerHTML` in the last line of your function, `innerHTML` is also what you should be applying the `replace` on:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo");

  var pat = /\:\s?\d*/;

  var res = str.innerHTML.replace(pat, ': 54321');

  str.innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "Movies: 12344" with "Movies: 54321" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">Movies: 1234!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `str` variable is not equal to the text node within the element, but rather the element itself. To make `str` equal to the text within the element, try the following.

```
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract text from the element before replacing.

```
//Replace the digits
var res = str.innerHTML.replace(pat, ': 54321');
```